# Retool: Create sidebar to dynamically change a container window's components

Tags: retool

I am trying to create a sidebar with a couple of buttons. I have one container and what I would like to do is on click of one of the buttons in the sidebar, it will show a different tabbed container that is within the main container component.  For example, the container is called "main_window" and I want to add 3 tabbed containers called "foo", "bar", "fizz".

My thought was to create a [temporary state] (https://docs.retool.com/docs/temporary-state) called "window_selected" and assign a state per window.  In other words:

```
{{state1.value}} == 1 then "foo"
{{state1.value}} == 2 then "bar"
{{state1.value}} == 3 then "fizz"
```

The docs also references setting these values running javascript code, but where do you actually run that code? For example, if I want to set a constructor for first load of the page, for example, to set state.setValue(value: 0) by default, where do I run this?

In the documentation it also states:
If you refresh your app (with a ⌘R), your temporary states will be lost. If you're looking to persist state between app refreshes, you should write back results to a database!

Therefore, I was considering using localstorage as I see there is a localstorage section, but the only reference to localstorage in the docs is [here](https://docs.retool.com/docs/javascript-overview).

Where do I set values for localstorage?  And, is there a way to run a transformer or query "onload"?

Ultimately, how do I create a dashboard where the page dynamically changes in a main window depending on which button I have highlighted in the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

We answered this question on our community forum here: https://community.retool.com/t/create-sidebar-to-dynamically-change-a-container-windows-components/2257